# app crashing when trying to connect Internet

Tags: java, android

I am working with android studio and whenever I try to connect to internet it show Dialog that "Unfortunately 'app name' stopped" and then if crashes.
I have updated the manifest file for permission as well. please provide any assistance, It might helpful.
Here is the code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    TextView msg;
    String user,pass;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        final EditText password;
        TextView regLabel;
        Button loginbt;
        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        regLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_label);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alert);
        regLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent register_form = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);
                startActivity(register_form);
            }
        });
        loginbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                user = username.getText().toString();
                pass = password.getText().toString();
                if(user.length()>0 && pass.length()>0) {
                    try {
                        new LoginProcess().execute("http://url.com");
                    } catch (Exception le) {
                        msg.setText("Error:" + le);
                    }
                }else{
                    msg.setText("Please Enter Username and Password!");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginProcess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            Dialog.setMessage("Checking Authentication..");
            Dialog.show();
        }
        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            if (Error != null) {
                msg.setText("Error in Login: " + Error);
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Content);
                    String orgPass = jsonObj.getString("password");
                    if (orgPass.equals(pass)) {
                        Intent rp = new Intent(Login.this, Menu.class);
                        startActivity(rp);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        msg.setText("Wrong Password");
                    }
                } catch (Exception je) {
                    msg.setText("Error:" + je);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please post stack trace from logcat

Comment: check `R.id.login`  is exists in `R.layout.login`

Comment: we need to see the logcat..

Comment: Reasons for this happening: Trying to connect to the internet from main thread, not having enough permissions. Check your logcat (if you are from command-line you can run `adb logcat *:E`, or from Android Studio on the "logcat" section)

Comment: @TomTsagk isn't the OP using AsyncTask? `new LoginProcess().execute("http://url.com");` so it's not on the UI thread?!

Comment: Now It's not crashing but not completing process...I made some changes at url with space and special character to convert in to equivalent tag(%27 for ' and  %20 for space). Dialog box is not completing. I tried to find out the reason and I think there is a problem executing command: Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

Comment: please provide any alternative code you have to perform the same task.